# Did .Net 4.0 change File.Exists?

Tags: .net-4.0

What used to work for me, when I would check if File.Exists now returns a false.

We recently updated to the 4.0 -- and now any files within my personal User folder return FALSE for File.Exists.

Anyone experience this or know of the issue?

(For example -  (File.Exists("C:\Users\Public\test.txt")) will equal TRUE but (File.Exists("C:\Users\peronalFolder.domain\test.txt")) always comes back FALSE)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have rights to access that folder?

Comment: I do... these all worked before.  Maybe some permission changes occurred but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Is this a fairly simple console app that reproduces this functionality?  Or something else?  If it's a web app, it will likely be running in a different App Pool than what you had under 2.0 and may have a different user context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that `File.Exists` changed.  It is more likely that your environment changed.  I would recommend looking into your App Pool settings (if relevant) as @Jesse mentioned.

You can attempt to identify if it is a .NET issue or an environmental issue by using the following **powershell** script as a unit test for file access:

```
$SourceFile = "c:\foo\Test.txt";

if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($SourceFile))  {
   "Source File exists"
}
else {
   "Source file ($Sourcefile) does not exist."
}
```

Comment: It seems that for some reason the permissions have changed somewhere... this once worked (files under my user folder) and now it doesn't.